# First law of thermodynamics: Can we always speak in terms of infinitesimal changes?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy-conservation, differentiation, calculus

While reading lecture notes for the course on thermodynamics I have encountered some tiny details that seem extremely important for the understanding of the topic. However, something seems amiss so, I was wondering if there are any underlying intricacies to these concepts or is it just levity of the language used in the lecture notes.

Often times in thermodynamics, in order to avoid introducing **ill-defined** variables of state (or for some other reasons), various constraints are placed on the phenomenon in question e.g. to speak of pressure-volume work, the process must be *quasistatic* as then we can equate thermodynamic pressure and mechanical pressure (example with a sliding piston) $\delta W=P\text{d}V$. Other instance is equation of state that works only in equilibrium, and there are many more of such constraints.

I do realize that the concepts above are not strictly connected but I wanted to outline my issue with thermodynamics. So, the **first law of thermodynamics** in the most general case is formulated as:
$$ \Delta U=\Delta Q-\Delta W.$$
Then in the discourse, some other vital concepts in thermodynamics are introduced based on the treatment of infinitesimal changes $\text{d}U$ and we very swiftly start confidently speaking of first law of thermodynamics in the following form:

$$\text{d}U=\delta Q - \delta W.$$

My question is, can we always speak of the total differential $\text{d}U$ even if the other states variables are not defined? Wouldn't the treatment of $\text{d}U$ imply that there is some state function $U$ regardless of whether the other state variables are defined? To further underscore what I mean; the isovolumetric heat capacity is defined as:
$$C_V=\lim\limits_{\Delta T\rightarrow0}\left(\frac{\Delta Q}{\Delta T}\right)_V$$
If the system does no work, then $\Delta U=\Delta Q$. Then:
$$C_V=\lim\limits_{\Delta T\rightarrow0}\left(\frac{\Delta U}{\Delta T}\right)_V=\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial T}\right)_V$$
Now, what must be this "constraint" that allows us to equate this limit with the partial derivative of the internal energy?

Comment: what "constraint" are you referring to?

Comment: By constraint I mean some condition under which the considerations are "valid", e.g. **under the condition**  that the process is quasistatic and the system does only pressure-volume work, we can write dU=dQ-PdV; when the condition ("constraint") does not hold the change in the internal energy is something different.

Comment: dU is the same for a quasistatic and non quasistatic process. It is a system property which means it doesn’t depend on the process

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of a Newtonian fluid?  This starts with the equation of state for the fluid, but recognizes that the state of compressive stress in a deforming fluid also depends not only on the local specific volume and temperature change, but also on the *rate* at which the fluid is deforming locally, as described by the velocity gradients in the fluid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> e.g. to speak of pressure-volume work, the process must be
> *quasistatic* as then we can equate thermodynamic pressure and mechanical pressure (example with a sliding piston) $\delta
> W=P\text{d}V$

A process need not be quasi-static to determine work. $PdV$ work for any process is determined using the external pressure. If the process happens to be quasistatic, then the $P$ is both the system and external pressure in equilibrium with one another.

> So, the **first law of thermodynamics** in the most general case is
> formulated as: $$ \Delta U=\Delta Q-\Delta W$$

Drop the deltas from heat and work. It makes no sense to talk about a "change" in heat or work. There are amounts of energy transferred in the form of heat and work. Your next differential equation of the first law correctly shows heat and work as inexact differentials, whereas internal energy (a property) is an exact differential.

> My question is, can we always speak of the total differential
> $\text{d}U$ even if the other states variables are not defined?

Yes, because internal energy is a system property independent of the process. A change in internal energy between two equilibrium states is the same regardless of the process. For example, it doesn't matter if the process is quasistatic or not.

> To further underscore what I mean; the isovolumetric heat capacity is
> defined as: $$C_V=\lim\limits_{\Delta T\rightarrow0}\left(\frac{\Delta
> Q}{\Delta T}\right)_V$$

That is not how the heat capacity at constant volume is defined.  It is defined in terms of internal energy and temperature according to:

$$c_{v}=\biggl (\frac{\delta u}{\delta T}\biggr )_V$$

> Now, what must be this "constraint" that allows us to equate this
> limit with the partial derivative of the internal energy?

The only constraints are constant volume and that the system consist of a single phase pure component.

Hope this helps.